# How to set image tag source from varbinary using asp net razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, razor, base64

I have a project that save any files like image to base64 to varbinary to database.

I want to load that varbinary or base64 to image tag source without using razor tag or direct query to database.

I have this code to download `file by id` from db :

```
public ActionResult Download(String Id)
        {


            if (Session["user"] == null)
                return RedirectToAction("Landing", "Home");

            try
            {
                var file = dbIntegrated.DATAFiles.Where(p => p.Id == Guid.Parse(Id)).FirstOrDefault();

                if (file.Data != null)
                {
                    string basesFile = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(file.Data.ToArray());
                    Byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(basesFile.Split(',')[1]);

                    return File(bytes, "multipart/form-data", file.Name);
                }
                else
                {
                    return File(file.Location + file.Name, "multipart/form-data", file.Name);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //return RedirectToAction("DownloadError", "File");
                return View();
            }            
        }
```

so if i want to download a file i just use it like this

```
http://mywebsite.com/file/download/someGuidAsFileID
```

But i afraid it will not work with this condition :

```
<img src="http://mywebsite.com/file/download/someGuidAsFileID" />
```

Please help me how to make that condition works, so i just need id of image file and place it on image source it will show the image?

Comment: This should work. Did you try it? Also if this is an image you'd better use the proper content type for it, like `image/jpeg` or `image/png` instead of `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: i try `multipart/form-data` but it not works, thanks i will try `image/jpeg` or `image/png`